# I don't want play game music if system sound is already playing

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm developing a game app which is having background music. but I don't want to play background music of game if system sound is already playing.Please help me.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/26735972/6207502

Answer (score 0):

All the user has to do is flip the switch on the side of the device (silent mode). Music will keep playing but app sounds will will be disabled.